# Chrome Extension and gmail.js blocking access to google api

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, gmail-api, gmail.js

I'm just playing around with a chrome extension based on this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/deepbreath-preventing-angry-emails-with-machine-learning .

When i use the extension for some reason I am unable to get the draft email's body using gmail.js https://github.com/josteink/gmailjs-node-boilerplate .

Using the gmail.js boilerplate,

```
    "use strict";

console.log("Extension loading...");
const jQuery = require("jquery");
const $ = jQuery;
const GmailFactory = require("gmail-js");
const gmail = new GmailFactory.Gmail($);
window.gmail = gmail;




/*
This code uses the Gmail library to observe emails being sent, turn them into XML,
then return a json data, body, which is put into the request and parsed with ML.
*/

gmail.observe.on("load", () => {
  const userEmail = gmail.get.user_email();
  console.log("Hello, " + userEmail + ". This is your Rhea talking with a new version better loading!!");

  gmail.observe.on("view_email", (domEmail) => {
    console.log("Looking at email:", domEmail);
    const emailData = gmail.new.get.email_data(domEmail);
    console.log("Email data:", emailData);
  });


//var main = function () {

  gmail.observe.on('save_draft', function (id, url, body, xhr) {

    var draftId = url['permmsgid'];

    console.log("draft saved" + draftId)

  });

});
    //
```

The first two console logs are working correctly, so unsure as to the best way to handle this issue.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Could you post a working repository? The repo you provide does not even work... Did you update something before using it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, it appears the `save_draft` observer is not firing anymore after ["New Gmail" was introduced in 2018](https://blog.google/products/gmail/stay-composed-heres-quick-rundown-new-gmail/). I loaded your extension myself and confirmed that, while the `view_email` event is still firing as expected, `save_draft` is not. Gmail.js's developer [confirmed in a recent issue report](https://github.com/KartikTalwar/gmail.js/issues/601#issuecomment-566961692) that another event, `send_email`, has the same issue with the current version of Gmail. So it seems the script is not working as well as it used to.

If you still want to get this working, a few options are:

- Find an alternate Gmail.js event to use instead of `save_draft` that is still working
- Get the contents of `div.editable` using some other event handler, such as JavaScript's standard `onkeypress`
- Roll up your sleeves, debug the issue with the Gmail.js plugin, and send a pull request to its developer if you can find a fix

---

**Edit:** Here is a working solution using standard JS events `keydown` and `click` as well as a mutation observer to wait for the field to appear:

```
"use strict";

console.log("Extension loading...");
const jQuery = require("jquery");
const $ = jQuery;
const GmailFactory = require("gmail-js");
const gmail = new GmailFactory.Gmail($);
window.gmail = gmail;

function logInnerText(e) {
  console.log("New Email Body Text is: " + e.currentTarget.innerText);
}

gmail.observe.on("load", () => {
  const userEmail = gmail.get.user_email();
  console.log("Hello, " + userEmail + ". This is your extension talking!");

  gmail.observe.on("view_email", domEmail => {
    console.log("Looking at email:", domEmail);
    const emailData = gmail.new.get.email_data(domEmail);
    console.log("Email data:", emailData);
  });

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    let messageBodyField = document.querySelector("div.editable");
    if (
      messageBodyField &&
      !messageBodyField.getAttribute("data-found-by-my-extension")
    ) {
      messageBodyField.setAttribute("data-found-by-my-extension", true);
      messageBodyField.addEventListener("keydown", logInnerText);
      messageBodyField.addEventListener("click", logInnerText);
    }
  });

  observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });
});
```

If you run into any performance issues, you can try searching within a lower-level tag than `document.body` when checking if the box exists. Let me know if you'd like any of it explained further.

Comment: Thanks man. Excellent work! With javascripts onkeypress - is there any documentation on approaching the solution with that?

Comment: Glad this worked for you! FYI - if you'd like to send me the bounty, you have to do that manually. Otherwise, I'll get only half of it when it expires in 12 hours and the other half will be trashed. :)

Comment: @MichaelHolborn from https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067 : A bounty can be awarded 24 hours after the bounty was started. You can award the bounty to any answer posted by anyone else, even an answer that has already been awarded one or more bounties (including by you).

To award the bounty manually, click on the +50 (or whatever bounty amount was allocated) button on the left side of the answer you want to award.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. Thank you!

Comment: Will ask more questions soon! I'm getting an error when I'm sending it to the API now saddly :( Super weird!